# The relativity of "<script src="

Tags: javascript, html, relative-path

So on a HTML page, when you link to a JavaScript file, is it the same as it actually being there (like include() in php) or does everything have to be relative to the folder that the js file is in?

eg if I have `<script src="scriptage/my.js"> </script>` in `index.html`, is a image file to the js file `'image.png'` or `'../image.png'`

Comment: It depends. Please clarify what you mean by "everything". What kinds of URLs are you using in what context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has no concept of files.  Although certain extensions may provide file read/write APIs, everything is relative to the document.

Comment: this probably answers the OP's question. In fact, it's close to impossible to find out the name of the current script file in an embed context

Comment: @Pekka: I believe that's [a work in progress](http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg23015.html) (and already supported in Firefox) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just like the php include(), it relates to the path of the file where you have attached the script. like here index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your images should be relative to the JavaScript file, not the calling document.